# Filtering, checking and processing pandas df based on statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example DF (400k rows):

```
NameID      Name      SNP      Sequence      Chromosome      positionOnChorm
AR1         AR1A      A/G     AVDJFJDSKFJVN      1              231231
AR2         AR1B      A/G     AVDJFJDSKFJVN      1              231231
BAR         BA1B      A/T     FFSJJSAJASDND      2              312333
BAR2        BA1B      A/T     FFSJAAAAACDDD      2              312333
AR3         AR1C      A/G     AVDJFJDSKFJVN      1              231231
CAR7        CAR1V     T/G     WEEEEEEEEEEEE      4              778787
...
```

In DF are genes. I need to divide it to two result data frame based on that scenario:
(Most important is Name for me but else data too.)

I. Check Chromosome and positionOnChorm. If it is duplicated (in AR example it will be 3 duplicated genes) I need to confirm that checking SEQUENCE. If it's same I can drop duplicated, keep first gene and put it to `finalDF`.

If chromosome and position are the same but sequence is different - I need to put all of them to `DuplDF`.

If it's only one same combination of chromosome/position: it should be moved to `finalDF`.

So based on example:

`finalDF` should be:

```
NameID      Name      SNP      Sequence      Chromosome      positionOnChorm

AR1         AR1A      A/G     AVDJFJDSKFJVN      1              231231
CAR7        CAR1V     T/G     WEEEEEEEEEEEE      4              778787
```

`DuplDF` should be:

```
BAR         BA1B      A/T     FFSJJSAJASDND      2              312333
BAR2        BA1B      A/T     FFSJAAAAACDDD      2              312333
```

So I had that idea:

1. I created a position list by `value_counts` and tried to filter it by if statement. But in the list, I didn't have a chromosome. That's an important coz gene on another chromosome can be same position, and it's different gene.
   Second problem - it's really time taking solution. Even If I would build a statement correctly using both chromosome and position - it takes hours to process one DF.
2. I tried used to merge, used in different ways, but honestly, I don't know how I should create it to be fit in my case.
3. I theoretically think about grup my genes and then processing it in `tempDF`, but I don't know it's even possible in easy way. I found `group_by` but in doc i read it works only with one col?

Can someone give me an advice how can I effectively solve my problem?

Comment: If one sequence of the chromosome 1 out of 3 doesn't have the same sequence, do you need the 3 lines (meaning 1 duplicate) or only the unique combinations to be moved to DuplDF?

Comment: _I found group_by but in doc i read it works only with one col?_
Also you can use groupby on multiple columns of course `df.groupby(['colA','colB'])`